# Regex to select whole word if part matches

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to be able to select the WHOLE word, before and after the match...

Currently it only selects the part in the word that's matched. So if i'm looking after `"Dog"` in the word `"Doglets"` it selects Dog.

I want it to select Doglets. And I also want it to select letsDog if that was the case.

```
return html.replace(new RegExp('(\\b)(' + query + ')(\\b)', 'ig'), "<span class='search-enlight'>$&</span>");
```

UPDATE:

```
function filterSearchWords() {
    var query = $("#searchquery").val();

    go(query);
    function go(query) {
        $.extend($.expr[':'], {
            'containsi': function (elem, i, match, array) {
                return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase()
                .indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
            }
        });

        $(".search-result p:containsi(" + query + ")").html(function (_, html) {
            return html.replace(new RegExp('(\\b)( \\w*' + query + '\\w*)(\\b)', 'ig'), "<span class='search-enlight'>$&</span>")
        });
        $(".search-result h2 a:containsi(" + query + ")").html(function (_, html) {
            return html.replace(new RegExp('(\\b)( \\w*' + query + '\\w*)(\\b)', 'ig'), "<span class='search-enlight'>$&</span>")
        });
        console.log(query);
    }
}
```

It matches full words now, however it does not match with capitalized letters, the i flag seems not to work

HTML:

```
div class="search-result">
                                <span class="thumb" style="font-family: 'draftit'; float: left;">&#xe811;</span>&nbsp;

                                <h2 class="title"><a href="/produkter/malins-testprodukt/skatteavdrag/berakning-av-skatteavdrag/skatteavdrag-nar-skattesedel-inte-har-lamnats/">Skatteavdrag n&#228;r skattesedel inte har l&#228;mnats</a></h2>
                                <p>
                                    Arbetsgivare f&#229;r fr&#229;n Skatteverket besked om hur skatteavdraget f&#246;r respektive anst&#228;lld ska ber&#228;knas. Se avsnittet  tabellavdrag och CSR-f&#246;rfr&#229;gan . Arbetstagaren beh&#246;ver d&#229; inte l...
                                </p>

                            </div>
```

Comment: Try `/([^ ]*Dog[^ ]*)/`

Comment: No results at all :/ @Lauromine

Comment: @Codehiker post the html please !

Comment: @chsdk Posted html in first post!

Comment: `p:containsi(" + query + ")` must be `p:contains(" + query + ")` there's an extra `i` after contains, no?

Comment: Its because I created an own contains function, by default it only looks for matches with the same capital letters. 

containsi doesnt depend on capitals.

Comment: That function works though, but when I added your code everything else worked but the capital letter matches... Must be something with the regex?

Comment: Okay I get it, but I don't what's wrong with it, try to replace `ig` with `igm`.

Comment: If I try another regex it matches with all capital letters :S

Comment: igm didn't change anything ;/

Comment: Fixed it. was a space in the regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case you need to include the whole word in your Regex, try the following one:

```
(\\b)( \\w*'+ query + '\\w*)(\\b)
```

And your code will be:

```js
var html = "The Doggy dog is with Doglets and Doggy too!";
var query = "dog";

document.write(html.replace(new RegExp('(\\b)( \\w*' + query + '\\w*)(\\b)', 'ig'), "<span class='search-enlight'>$&</span>"));
```

```css
.search-enlight {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Must be a typo in there. cant run it @chsdk

Comment: Almost! Now it selects the full words that match, however it broke something with the casesensetivity. dog does not match with Dog.

Comment: Do you want it to be case sensitive? if so just remove the  `i` flag from it.

Comment: No I do not, I want it to match even if it has capitalized letters. But it does not.

Comment: If you see in my snippet, it matches `Dog`, `dog` and `Doggy`.

Answer (score 2):

Could you post a sample of your html before being replaced ?
cause /([^ ]*Dog[^ ]*)/ should work, but you seems to have some \b in your string around your keyword so the answer should be

```
([^ ]*)(\\bdog\\b)([^ ]*)
```

for a string like

```
test of \bdog\blet
```

Comment: return html.replace(new RegExp('([^ ]*)(\\'+query +'\\b)([^ ]*)', 'ig'), "<span class='search-enlight'>$&</span>");

Doesnt work at all :(

Comment: you forget a b after \\'+query, anyway can you post a sample of your html variable ? thanks

Comment: div class="search-result">
                                <span class="thumb" style="font-family: 'draftit'; float: left;">&#xe811;</span>&nbsp;

                                <h2 class="title"><a href="/produkter/malins-testprodukt/skatteavdrag/berakning-av-skatteavdrag/skatteavdrag-nar-skattesedel-inte-har-lamnats/">Skatteavdrag n&#228;r skattesedel inte har l&#228;mnats</a></h2>
                                <p>
                                    Arbetsgivare f&#229;r fr&#229;n Skatteverket besked om hur skatteavdraget f&#246;r respektive anst&#228;lld ska

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead: `\b.*?dog.*?\b`.

The *problem* with your expression is that you are attempting to match the `query` part surrounded by word boundaries. Adding `.*?` before and after will instruct the regex engine to do a non greedy search for other characters which are between the substring you are interested and the word boundaries:

```
return html.replace(new RegExp('(\\b)(.*?' + query + '.*?)(\\b)', 'ig'), "<span class='search-enlight'>$&</span>");
```

Example available [here](https://regex101.com/r/wN6tI9/3).

Comment: This does not work: return html.replace(new RegExp('\b.*?' +query+'.*?\b', 'ig'), "<span class='search-enlight'>$&</span>");

Comment: Actually `.*` will include spaces in there so the whole sentence will be taken, and only specific words.

Comment: @Codehiker: Maybe you need to escape the `\b`? In your example you had 2 slashes.

Comment: @chsdk: That is why there is the `?` operator, so as to make the `*` operator non greedy.

Comment: Okay, I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
\w*Dog\w*
```

[Test is here.](https://regex101.com/r/sq16Na/1)